# Form submit stopping other functions working with scrollify.move?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-scrollify

I have a 1 page website that is using scrollify.js.

I have 2 buttons to scroll the window to the relevant section for filling out the form and returning to the top of the page.

The first button is (icon2) with an (a) tag with a class of scrollToB.

The 2nd button (home-btn) with another (a) tag and a class of scrollTo that fades in and out so you can return to the top section on clicking this button.

Both functions to scroll and fade in and out are working until i click submit on the form and although the fade function still works on the button the seperate click functions on the 2 buttons (scrollify.move) have stopped working? This behaviour is the same whether the form fails validation or is sent?

a working example is www.devonfoodmovement.com

I have searched for hours and cant find anything relevant?

All scripts/styles are being loaded from my functions.php file

Index (front-page.php)

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <article id="section_1">
        <section class='section-class' data-section-name="devonfoodmovement">
        <?php include('home-layout.php');?>
        </section>
    </article>
    <article id="section_2">
        <section class='section-class' data-section-name="contact us">
        <?php include('form.php');?>
        </section>
        <div class="home-btn"><a href="#section_1" class="scrollTo"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></div>
    </article>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

home-layout.php

```
    <?php ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo-image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <h1>Devon Food Movement</h1>
            <h2>Website under construction <br class="textbreak">follow us below on ...</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="icons">
            <div class="icon1"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/luke-fearon-853606158/" target="_blank"></a></div>
            <div class="icon2"><a href="#section_2" class="scrollToB"></a></div>
            <div class="icon3"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/_u/five_mile_food" target="_blank"></a></div>
            <div class="icon3m"><a href="instagram://user?username=five_mile_food"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

functions.php

```
    <?php
    function register_my_menus() {
        register_nav_menus(
                array( 'header_menu' => __( 'Header Menu', 'DevonFoodMovement'),
                       'footer_menu' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'DevonFoodMovement')
                     )
                );
    }
    add_action('init', 'register_my_menus');

    /* GOOGLE FONTS */

    function DFM_styles()
    {
        wp_register_style('DFM', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('DFM');


    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'DFM_styles');

    function DFM_form()
    {
        wp_register_style('DFMform-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('DFMform-css');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'DFM_form');

    function DFM_scripts()
    {
        wp_register_script('j-query-min', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('j-query-min');

        wp_register_script('j-query-mob-min', 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('j-query-mob-min');

        wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/modernizr-1.6.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );

        wp_register_script('scrollify-min', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-scrollify@1.0.17/jquery.scrollify.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('scrollify-min');

        wp_register_script('jquery-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customjs.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-custom');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'DFM_scripts');

    function load_fonts() 
    {
        wp_register_style('et-googleFonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'et-googleFonts');
    }
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_fonts');

        /* 
         * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
         * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
```

custom.js file

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('article').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'}).css({'width':($(window).width())+'px'});
        $(window).resize(function(){
        $('article').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'}).css({'width':($(window).width())+'px'});
        });
    });
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        $(function() {
            $.scrollify({
            section: ".section-class",
            sectionName : "section-name",
            /*interstitialSection : ".footer-end",*/
            scrollSpeed: 1000,
            setHeights: true
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).scroll(function (){
        if(window.location.href === "http://devonfoodmovement.com/#devonfoodmovement"){
        $('.home-btn').fadeOut(500);

        } else if(window.location.href === "http://devonfoodmovement.com/#contact-us") {
        $('.home-btn').fadeIn(500).css('display','block');
        }    
    });
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".scrollTo").click(function() {
            $.scrollify.move(0);
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".scrollToB").click(function() {    
            $.scrollify.move(1);    
        });
    });
```

form.php

```
    <?php include ('form_process.php');?>
    <div class="grey">
        <div class="container-contact">
            <form id="contact" method="post" >
                <div id="column-contact-left">
                <div class='contact-logo'></div>
                <h3>Contact the Devon Food Movement</h3>
                <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                    <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" name="name1" value="<?= $name ?>" >
                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
                <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                    <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >
                </fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
                </div>
                <div id="column-contact-right">
                <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                    <textarea id="field-no-ui" placeholder="Type your Message Here...." name="message" value="<?= $message ?>" tabindex="3" ></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey" ></div>
                <span class="captcha-failed"><?= $captchafailed; ?></span>
                <span class="sent"><?= $sent; ?></span>
                <fieldset id="field-no-ui">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

form-process.php

```
    <?php
    function post_captcha($user_response) {
        $fields_string = '';
        $fields = array(
            'secret' => 'secret',
            'response' => $user_response
        );
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
            $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
    $res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $name_error = $email_error = $captchafailed = "";
    $name = $email = $message = $sent = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) AND (!$res['success'])) {    
            $captchafailed = "please check reCaptcha";
    }
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name1"])) {
            $name_error = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
            $email_error = "Email is required";
        } else {
            $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $email_error = "Invalid email format";
            }
        }
        if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
            $message = "";
        } else {
            $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
        }
        if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and ($res['success']) ){
            $message_body = '';
            unset($_POST['submit']);
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
                $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
            }
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $to = '@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
            $headers = 'From:' . $email . "\n" . 'Reply-to: ' . $email . "\n"  ;
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                $sent = "Message sent";
                $name = $email = $message = '';
            }
        }    
    }
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of issue here with the way this is put together.
First thing you can start with is to prevent the default behaviour of your move links.

```
$(".scrollTo").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.scrollify.move(0);
});
```